# Mysterious phenomenon on iPad with iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

My app are designed to work in portrait and landscape orientations. If the app is launched while the device is hold in portrait, everything works fine. And you can change the orientation to landscape, also working fine.

But when the app is first launched in landscape, then nothing works.
[image: Launched at landscape orientation]

All things are placed correctly, but touch events are only recognized in the left part of the display. Two Buttons on top right are not working.

In this state, the device is rotated to portrait, the display is unusable:
[image: Orientation changed to portrait]

Original screenshot! This only happens with iPad and iOS 8.x. With my old iPad 1 and iOS 5.1.1 everything works perfectly.

Sure, this is a bug in iOS 8.0. What can I do?

Comment: are you using nib but not storyboard?   This is a known issue.  When your viewController first loads it is not aware of the devices orientation.  Then when it presents the rotation stuff is not called.  If you had done a storyboard it would work.  If you had created it in code in the delegate with no nib then it actually broke a year earlier, with iOs7.  I'm tipping you have this issue on iPhone6+ as well, because that also is capable of running springboard in landscape.    You just need to find a way to trigger the layout code.

Comment: it is very hard do detect it's orientation from the start up, and it is not working well from iOS 6 :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
-(void)viewWillAppearAnimated:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppearAnimated:animated];

 BOOL landscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation]);
 BOOL ios8 = NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverPresentationController")!=NULL;

 if (landscape&&ios8) {

  NSLog(@"launch in landscape orientation problem!!");

  //if you handle rotation programatically this should do it..
[self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation] duration:0.0]; 

  //or if you use autolayout..
CGRect rct = CGRectZero;
rct.size.width = (CGFloat) fmaxf(((float)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height),((float)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width));
rct.size.height = (CGFloat) fminf(((float)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height),((float)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width));

[self.view setFrame:rct];

  }

}
```

Comment: viewWillAppearAnimated is not called - I did it in viewWillAppear, using the autolayout part, but it's the same as before. Even if it is possible to repair the view for landscape, the portrait view will have problems too because improper initialization by the OS.